# Going more than one time through my AutoCompletBox Selection_Changed event

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, autocomplete

I have an autoCompleteBox, where i write a name.

The probme is, I'm going through two(or more) times when I choose one element in the dropDownList.

I don't understand why, I only going through the populating event one time, so why more in the Selection Changed event more than one?

```
<myControl:AutoCompleteBox  x:Name="acpName"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            IsTabStop="False" 
                            IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                            MinimumPrefixLength="3"
                            ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateMatriculeCandidat}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=NameSource}"
                            Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" 
                            MinWidth="150"
                            FilterMode="None" />




 void acpName_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

   try
    {
        Emp itm = (Emp)acpName.SelectedItem;

        if (itm  != null)
        {
            itmEmpSelect.Surname= itm.Surname;
            itmEmpSelect.Id= itm.Id;
            itmEmpSelect.Birth= itm.Birth;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorWindow.CreateNew(ex);
    }
}
```

This happens even if I do nothing in my selection changed event. I really don't understand.
It seems hapenning when I have multiple choice after the populating event. But why?

Thank you.

Comment: Post your codebehind.cs code also

Comment: Yes forgot it, add it,  but it's very simple.

Comment: you are doing it inside which event?

Comment: Shit, a piece of code remove. Selection_changed.

Comment: which selection changed? autocomplete box? post the place where you bind autocompletebox

Comment: The place where I bind it? I do not understand that...

Comment: where do you assign the itemssource to autocompletebox.

Comment: No offense but, In the xaml code, there is a line : `ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=NameSource}"` . I just get a list of Employee with it.

Comment: from where do you get the Data ...

Comment: From a database; I only have a select req in the client side of my application. Explain your point a bit, because I don't understand why it could be anything but the xaml code or the code behind.

Comment: cant find where the problem is , put a breakpoint inside selection changed and capture how many times it is getting fired!

Comment: I already did it, and it's 2 ot 3 times.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38721/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-zaphod)